# Unable to access site cookie after LTI Launch

Tags: cookies, iframe, lti, canvas-lms

I have a small LTI application that integrates with canvas, and after the LTI launch I can't access the cookie.  This is failing in Safari (always) and Chrome (sometimes).

I am forcing the SameSite=LAX field of the cookie.

I'm not sure what else I should try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been numerous changes in Chrome (and other browsers) [regarding cookies and iframe.](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html). For LTI 1.3 launches this is extra difficult because of how you need to track the state of the launch in the cookie while processing the OIDC flow.

The basics of what is changing is there is now a 'SameSite' cookie policy, where `Only cookies set as SameSite=None; Secure will be available in third-party contexts, provided they are being accessed from secure connections.` So marking the cookies as `Secure` and `HTTP-Only` is a must in addition to the `SameSite=None`

Also in Safari, the third-party frame will have to request access to the [storage API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) before the cookie will be accessible.

Firefox is using a partitioned approach to the storage, and so the frame will behave as normal unless you then open your application as a new window then the cookie store may or may not follow depending on how the new window was created.

[Cookie Status](https://www.cookiestatus.com/) is an excellent resource to track how third party cookies work in the different browsers and what you should change to make it work.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't see there was a None option for samesite, I'll give that a try

Comment: Ugh, these cookies are a mess, thanks for the cookiestatus resource, there are more rules than I was thinking about.